# SSIS package doesn not run in a SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

My package is used to extract data from xml to a database.

When I execute the package in Visual Studio, it completes all tasks successfully.

But when I deployed the package to server and execute the package under Integration Services Catalog, it fails to get the xml schema file on a network drive with error message

The file "\UNC_Path\myfile.xsd" was not found

Comment: Have you tried it with `\\UNC_Path\myfile.xsd` instead? Note the doubled backslashes at the beginning.

Comment: yes , its not work

Comment: This is usually a permissions issue where the service account running SQL Server Agent doesn't have permissions to the directory and/or files.

Comment: thanks you, it's right ! not permission to account running sql server agent
So i add permission , and it's Work

Answer (score 0):

before uploading to the server, you must leave the path in the variable environment as a string, and you must add the variable to the path that reads the file

checkout here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-variables?view=sql-server-ver16